# Magento 2.3.1 - Issue with catalog search when using php7.2-fpm

Tags: magento2.3.1, php-7.2, ubuntu, php-fpm, search-result

When we search any string from the search text box, We have encountered a 500 server error into the search result page in our live web site or search page getting blank.

When we check in logs or report, it didn't give us any errors.

When we check our server apache log file then we find below errors.

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4769:tid 140509781169920] [client
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.x:58274] Premature end of script headers: index.php,
>   referer: example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pink
>
> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4769:tid 140509781169920] [client
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.x:58274] AH01070: Error parsing script headers, referer:
>   example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pink
>
> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4769:tid 140509781169920] (22)Invalid
>   argument: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.x:58274] AH01075: Error dispatching
>   request to : , referer: example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=pink

**Our server has apache version 2.4 , PHP 7.2 FPM and HTTP 2 protocol.**

**Also When we disable magento cache then it's work fine.
With PHP 7.2(not using PHP-7.2 FPM) it's also work perfectly.
Till I debug I found issue when php 7.2 FPM is running and looks like some issue with the proxy_fcgi module.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!!

Comment: Possible to check with memory limit.

Comment: Our memory limit is 1024M. So this is not a memory limit issue.

Comment: Check this one: https://magehit.com/blog/solving-500-internal-server-error-in-magento-2/

Comment: Already checked with that but shows some error of proxy_fcgi module of apache2 which used by php fpm.

Comment: I have update my question after done some of debugging.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to look at this [Github issue here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6401). Magento is compiling a list of product IDs to send as a cache header but the header ends up being too long because the header string includes all children of each of the configured items in the result set. This was happening for us on one specific listing  page, but it's really any result that has too many configured items.

I was able to fix it by making the change recommended in the last comment:

Edit `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Plugin/Frontend/ProductIdentitiesExtender.php`

Comment out the line here (or the whole block):

```
foreach ($this->configurableType->getChildrenIds($subject->getId()) as $childIds) {
  foreach ($childIds as $childId) {
     // $identities[] = Product::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $childId;
  }
}
```

For me this was line 40.

Comment: That seemed to have solved the issue for me. Alternatively you can put this in `di.xml` file in any custom module:  `<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="product_identities_extender" disabled="true" />
    </type>`

Comment: Zankar, I owe you big time. Just adding a simple plugin with that di.xml fixed that issue for me :)