# Cannot disable frontend plugin "product_identities_extender"

Tags: magento2.3, plugin

I wanted to disable the frontend plugin "product_identities_extender" from the module ConfigurableProduct, because this plugin generates too big headers for apache servers.
Which results in the known issue [Magento 2.3.1 - Issue with catalog search when using php7.2-fpm](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279542/magento-2-3-1-issue-with-catalog-search-when-using-php7-2-fpm)

I tried to add a module /MyVendor/MyModule to not overwrite Magento core code.
In `/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="product_identities_extender" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

I'm not sure why the plugin wasn't disabled. Do I need something else to disable a Magento plugin?

Comment: Did you get this to work? If so would you be able to share the code of your module? I am looking for the same solution since I don't prefer editing Magento core code.

Answer (score 0):

Make module depended to Magento_Catalog at module.xml